# How can I map a duplicately named field when deserializing using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a simple Java class that looks like this:

```
public class AllAdverts {

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value="id", ignoreUnknown=true)
    public static class Advert {

        @JsonProperty(value="_id")
        public String advertId;

        public String adgroupId;
    }

    public List<Advert> adverts;

    public AllAdverts(String json) throws IOException {
        this.adverts = MyUtils.mapper.readValue(json, 
                new TypeReference<List<Advert>>(){});
    }
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize the following bit of JSON:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "535788abf789b8916a8b456e",
        "adgroup_id": "535788abf789b8916a8b456c",
        "subcampaign_id": "535788abf789b8916a8b4569",
        "id": 6005879321807,
    },
    {
        "_id": "535788abf789b8916a8b456f",
        "adgroup_id": "535788abf789b8916a8b456c",
        "subcampaign_id": "535788abf789b8916a8b4569",
        "id": 6005879319007,
    }
]
```

When i pass in the JSON into the constructor of the class `AllAdverts`, the JSON gets mapped properly except the field called `advertId`.

As you can see, the JSON has two fields called `id` and `_id`, both of which I think Jackson treats as `id` and therefore, I am unable to load this. How can I resolve this issue? I've been digging through the docs and thought that the `JsonProperty` annotation would solve this, but it hasn't worked. While `adgroupId` has a value, `advertId` is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is you mapper consuming/removing underscores and replacing the uppercase letters to lowercase ones to fill the bean properties? Because that's what seems to be happening. Jackson would not fill the `adgroupId` field if not.

Check your mapper.

Here follows my code working with no problems at all (realize that I had to annotate the `adgroupId` field because of the name difference between the json and pojo field:

**Main.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Main().start();
    }

    public List<Advert> adverts;

    private void start() throws Exception {

        String jsonString =
                "[" +
                    "{" +
                        "\"_id\": \"535788abf789b8916a8b456e\"," +
                        "\"adgroup_id\": \"535788abf789b8916a8b456c\"," +
                        "\"subcampaign_id\": \"535788abf789b8916a8b4569\"," +
                        "\"id\": 6005879321807," +
                    "}," +
                    "{" +
                        "\"_id\": \"535788abf789b8916a8b456f\"," +
                        "\"adgroup_id\": \"535788abf789b8916a8b456c\"," +
                        "\"subcampaign_id\": \"535788abf789b8916a8b4569\"," +
                        "\"id\": 6005879319007," +
                    "}" +
                "]";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            Advert advert = mapper.readValue(jsonObject.toString(), Advert.class);

            System.out.println("advertId: " + advert.advertId);
            System.out.println("adgroupId: " + advert.adgroupId);
        }

    }

}
```

**Advert.java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "id", ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Advert {

    public Advert() {}

    @JsonProperty(value = "_id")
    public String advertId;

    @JsonProperty(value = "adgroup_id")
    public String adgroupId;

}
```

I'm using Jackson 2.4.1.

Comment: It seems that I was using an incorrect annotation of the same name and therefore the chaos. Your answer helped me pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to provide custom names for all properties using `JsonProperty` annotation. See example:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "id", ignoreUnknown = true)
class Advert {

    @JsonProperty(value = "_id")
    public String advertId;

    @JsonProperty(value = "adgroup_id")
    public String adgroupId;

    // getters, setters

}
```